# Qt5 cmake Windows Linker Error

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, linker

I just wanted to start a new project which uses Qt in combination with CMake. I (hope I) followed the docs, but it seems as if the linker is not doing its work correctly:

```
CMakeFiles\QtTest.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `QString::QString(char const*)':
P:/Qt/5.9.1/msvc2015_64/include/QtCore/qstring.h:659: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN7QString16fromAscii_helperEPKci'
CMakeFiles\QtTest.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `QTypedArrayData<unsigned short>::deallocate(QArrayData*)':
P:/Qt/5.9.1/msvc2015_64/include/QtCore/qarraydata.h:237: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN10QArrayData10deallocateEPS_yy'
```

I'm using mingw-w64 (the x86_64 installation) with CLion and its bundled CMake and Qt 5.9.1. My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(QtTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)


# Qt
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(Qt5_NO_LINK_QTMAIN ON)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH P:/Qt/5.9.1/msvc2015_64/lib/cmake)
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)

get_target_property(QtCore_location Qt5::Core LOCATION)
message("QtCore version ${Qt5Core_VERSION} is at ${QtCore_location}")

# QtTest executable
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(QtTest ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(QtTest Qt5::Core)
```

When creating the build files it outputs (correctly) `QtCore version 5.9.1 is at P:/Qt/5.9.1/msvc2015_64/bin/Qt5Core.dll`
The main.cpp contains just a call to QString for testing purposes:

```
#include <QtCore/QString>

int main() {
    QString string = QString("test");
}
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: You need Qt binaries built with mingw instead of Visual Studio.

Comment: That makes sense - I'll give it a try. So do I just need to install the precompiled binaries or is the toolchain needed aswell?

Comment: Binaries should be fine. I assume your  mingw toolchain works.